# javaFX css id selector with class selector not working

Tags: java, css, javafx

***Edit(9/05/2016):***

**Check the answer i have written..**

> Part 1

*I use **this css for all TabPanes of the app**:*

```
.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
   -fx-opacity: 0.0;    
 }


.tab-pane{
  -fx-tab-min-width:90.0px;
}


.tab-pane .tab{
 -fx-background-color: orange;
 -fx-background-radius:0.0 20.0 0.0 20.0;
 -fx-focus-color: transparent;
 -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;   
}

.tab-pane .tab:selected{
  .....
}

 .tab .tab-label { 
     .....
 }

 .tab:selected .tab-label { 
  ....
 }
```

> Part 2)

But i have a **TabPane** with with **id="SpecialTabPane"** and i want it to be costumized with different css values so:

```
 #SpecialTabPane.tab{
   -fx-background-color:cyan;
   -fx-background-radius:20 20 0 0;
   -fx-padding:3em 0em 3em 0em; 
   -fx-cursor:hand; 
 }

 #SpecialTabPane.tab:selected{
   -fx-background-color:magenta;
 }
```

> **The Problem**

Part 2 css changes all TabPanes.Why this is happening?**It must select only the tabPane with id="SpecialTabPane" and class selector=".tab"**... I am using Java 1.8_91

**Edit:**

I found the answer it has to do with css and how the children inherit from parents.

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE]? It seems it should work, but it's a bit strange to give a tab pane a style class of `tab`; as the individual tabs already have that class.

Comment: @James_D I want to make the TabPane with this ID different from the other TabPanes here i give the css only for tab but i want to change also and other things like rotate the text-label of tab but i want this only for this TabPane.Actually part 2 code not works at all without a space between ID and .tab...Thanks for help.

Comment: But as you said, you apply the id to the *tab pane*, not to the *tab*. Unless you explicitly add the style class `tab` to the *tab pane* (which would be odd), the selector should not actually select anything. Post a [MCVE].

Comment: @James_D i try to understand .tab or .tab .text-label are build in javaFX?In css with html if i use selector p is selecting all the paragraphs but here i have to use .tab how this is working internally in javaFX.If i create a new control how i can do this thing if it has subcontrols like a circle with subcontrol text for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might be useful for others so i am posting the answer.

What i wanted to achieve is this:

[image]

**The problem was that i had a TabPane which had as a children another TabPane so the child inherits the css values from parent.**

I had modified the css (but before using this you had to add this **Java** code):

```
parentTabPane.setId("SpecialTabPane");
parentTabPaneTab.setId("STab");
```

CSS Code:

```
#SpecialTabPane #STab.tab .tab-label{
  -fx-text-fill:white;
  -fx-rotate:90.0; 
}

#SpecialTabPane #STab.tab:selected .tab-label{
    -fx-text-fill:white;
}

#SpecialTabPane #STab.tab{
  -fx-background-color:black;
  -fx-background-radius:20.0 20.0 0.0 0.0;
  -fx-padding:3.0em 0.0em 3.0em 0.0em; 
  -fx-cursor:hand;  
  -fx-effect: innershadow(two-pass-box, white, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

> Explaining some of css:

Let's say this piece of code:

```
#SpecialTabPane #STab.tab
```

[For every item with **id selector** #SpecialTabPane that has a subitem with **id** #Stab and **class selector** .tab do this..... ]

That's the key if you remove #STab it selects all the tabs from parent TabPane and Children TabPanes

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you need to understand the structure of the components you are trying to style. If you haven't already, download [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) and use that to inspect the components so that you understand how the different parts of a `TabPane` are organized and which styles apply to the different parts.

Then you need to work on the selectors so that you find the specific classes you want to alter. You are looking for a `.tab` that is a descendent of a component with the id `SpecialTabPane`. You can either do that with descendent selectors, which says "a tab anywhere below a component called SpecialTabPane", or with child selectors which look for particular children.

The descendent selector would be:

```
#SpecialTabPane .tab {
```

Note the space between the id and the .tab, otherwise you are just adding the tab class to the SpecialTabPane itself.

A child selector would be, for example:

```
#SpecialTabPane > .tab-header-area > * > .tab {
```

Using child selectors usually gives better performance, and is more accurate because it targets specific combinations of components, which avoids unwanted results. With the descendent version, you are saying that a component with class `.tab` that appears *anywhere* underneath `SpecialTabPane` must use that style, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I will check this and ... Thanks for help

Comment: I had found what i wanted!